# $\ E[(X-c)^2]\geq E[(X-EX)^2]$

Tags: probability

Prove that:

$\ E[(X-c)^2]\geq E[(X-EX)^2] $ where $c$ is some constant.

I know that $\ E[(X-c)^2]=E[X]^2-2cE[X]+c^2$ and that $E[(X-EX)^2] =D[X]$.

Comment: Can you find value $c$ that gives minimum of the  function $f(c)=a^2-2ca+c^2$?

Comment: Basically, proving the inequality is equivalent to proving that the map $c\mapsto\Bbb E[(X-c)^2]$ is minimized when $c=\mu=\Bbb E[X]$. To show this, denoting by $a=\mu=\Bbb E[X]$, your map is $c\mapsto a^2-2ca+c^2$ which has a critical point at $c=a$ with second derivative being $2 (\gt 0)$ at $c=a$, thus showing it's a minimum.

Comment: Sure. It's at $c=a$

Answer (score 1):

Let $Y$ have mean $0$.

Then: $$\mathbb{E}\left(Y-d\right)^{2}=\mathbb{E}Y^{2}-2d\mathbb EY+d^{2}=\mathbb{E}Y^{2}+d^{2}\geq\mathbb{E}Y^{2}$$

Now substitute $Y:=X-\mathbb{E}X$ and $d=c-\mathbb{E}X$ in order
to get:

$$\mathbb{E}\left(X-c\right)^{2}=\mathbb{E}\left(Y-d\right)^{2}\geq\mathbb{E}Y^{2}=\mathbb{E}\left(X-\mathbb{E}X\right)^{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there:
$$
\begin{align}
E\!\left[(X-c)^2\right]
&=E\!\left[X^2\right]-2cE[X]+c^2\\
&=E\!\left[X^2\right]-E[X]^2+\left(E[X]-c\right)^2\\
&=E\!\left[\left(X-E[X]\right)^2\right]+\left(E[X]-c\right)^2
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$E[X]^2-2(E[X] + a)E[X]+(E[X] + a)^2 = E[X]^2-(E[X])^2 + a^2 > E[X]^2-(E[X])^2 = E[X]^2-2E[X]E[X]+E[X]^2$$

for any real non-zero $a$.

That makes $E[X]$ the point of global minimum of $f(c) = E[X]^2-2cE[X]+c^2$